# a way to secure data type in Ruby

Tags: ruby, types, initialization

I'm a new user of Ruby. As far I can see it is very easy to change a variables(object) class

```
#create an object 
n=1
n.class
=> Fixnum

n="Abc"
n.class
=> String
```

Is it a way to secure a data type of the variable? For example like in Java, when the variable is an integer it cannot take other values than integers.

Thank you!

Comment: You can check the type of a value. Why do you need to do that?

Comment: No, there’s no way to do this for a variable in Ruby. The best option is just to keep everything readable so the type of a variable is obvious at any given time.

Comment: I just want to be sure that if the expected variable is an integer is remained as an integer and all the methods of this class are valid. Is the solution always  to check the data type of the variable before going through  methods?

Comment: Then you are trying to use Ruby as a statically typed language. It's not. Either use it as dynamically typed or use another language (if you have a legitimate reason to need the static typing).

Comment: A check like `raise TypeError, "expected Integer, got #{n.class}" unless n.is_a?(Integer)` would work. But usually you would just proceed with the wrong (or unexpected) "type" and eventually have a `NoMethodError` due to a missing method.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

In Ruby, you can only operate on objects, but variables aren't objects, so there is no way to ask a variable about its type.

Also, there is no concept of "type" in Ruby.

Comment: Well, depends on what you call a type. But surely not what OP imagines.

Comment: In OO, "type" is basically synonymous with "protocol", so it is basically the set of messages it understands and how it reacts to them.